# Adjective or Noun for Describing a Written Entity Devoid of Meaning

Tags: single-word-requests

I wrote a blog post that was about pretty much nothing, but couldn’t come up with a good word to describe its lack of meaning. I was hoping for a more interesting word than just *meaningless*.

Comment: *Seinfeldian*, perhaps?

Comment: That's a little bit too pop-culture for me. Ideally I'd like to avoid slang on this one.

Comment: *It is a tale
Told by an idiot, full of sound and fury,
Signifying nothing.*

Comment: It's funny because without google I would have had no idea what you were talking about

Comment: Ain't the internet great?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider *[inane](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inane)*. As defined by *Collins English Dictionary*

> senseless, unimaginative, or empty; unintelligent: *inane remarks*

Similarly

> - fatuous
> - vacuous
> - mindless
> - asinine
> - puerile
> - vapid

Comment: Inane is good and asinine is even better. Well played.

Comment: I rather liked the Shakespeare one better — even if it would have required an ungainly number of hyphens. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could call it a *ramble*.

If you wanted a pejorative word, you could call it *drivel*.